# Setup a cron on a bash script but its not running

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I have a bash script in the server and I want to run the script every weekday at 10:30 am, so I set up corn job like this:

crontab -e

30 10 * * 1-5 /home/ubuntu/mydir/scripts/. myscript.sh

but it is not running ...Can anyone help me have I missed any steps?

Comment: `/home/ubuntu/mydir/scripts/myscript.sh` and make sure you `chmod +x myscript.sh`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I tried this but not working ....this is a bash script if I manually run the script I used this command " .  myscript.sh"

Comment: If you used `.`, it may be a different type of script. Try with `/bin/bash /home/ubuntu/mydir/scripts/myscript.sh` if `muscript` is in such directory. But *sourced* script are often sourced for a reason, so they may not completely work.

Comment: @NiladriDey : If cron can't run a program, there should be something written on stderr, but cron sends stdout and stderr by default by email. Did you check this?

Comment: Also note that cron generally interprets scripts with `/bin/sh` so any of the bashisms you have used will not work. That is why you also need to specify the interpreter, wtih with a `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your script or by executing your scrips at `/bin/bash -c "/home/ubuntu/mydir/scripts/myscript.sh"` -- in which case your script need not be executable. Sorry for the confusion. Note, when you run the script with `./name.sh` the `./` explicitly disambiguates the script to run. It says run the script at the absolute path `${PWD}/name.sh` and don't bother searching the `PATH` for it.

Answer (score 0):

You ask cron to execute the command

```
/home/ubuntu/mydir/scripts/. myscript.sh
```

But `/home/ubuntu/mydir/scripts/.` is a directory, not a file. The `.` is a special directory entry refering to the directory itself, hence your command is just a somewhat complicated way to write

```
/home/ubuntu/mydir/scripts myscript.sh
```

and hence cron can't run it. It should give an error message, though. When I run a command like this using, for instance, `ash`, I get the message

**.: Permission denied**

because a directory of course does not have permission  to be executed.

If the script is intended for bash, you would write

```
/bin/bash /path/to/myscript.sh
```

or you put a `#!` line for bash into myscript.sh and have as crontab entry just

```
/path/to/myscript.sh
```

Comment: as per your advice, I set up cronjob like this                                                                     46 17 * * 1-5 /bin/bash /home/ubuntu/path/test.sh    and the file start with #/ /bin/sh   still no luck .....have I missed anything ?

Comment: The buggy `#!` line does not matter in this case. What does "no luck" mean? You missed perhaps doing some debugging. For instance, you could run it with `-x` and investigate the log to see where it bails out. cron will send you stdout and stderr by mail; alternatively, you could redirect stdout and stderr to a log file.